# Making an image slider but the background image won't respond to other properties?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i recently just got some help with this code but and it works as a slider of background images, the only issue is that the background image isn't responding to the background image size property in the css and now the images are zoomed in fully when i want them to cover the div.

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

So here is my HTML

```
<div id="headbar" onload="photoA()">
    <div class="headbar-title">THE ALL NEW 14 RANGE</div>
    <div class="button">FIND OUT MORE</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var imageCount = 1;
        var total = 6;
        window.setInterval(function photoA() {
           var headbar = document.getElementById('headbar');
           imageCount = imageCount + 1;
           if(imageCount > total){imageCount = 1;}   
           headbar.style.background = "url('../img/img"+ imageCount +".JPG') no-repeat center center";
         }
       ,1000);
     </script>
</div>
```

Here is my css

```
#headbar {
  height: 50vh;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-top: 60px;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center;
  color: #eee;
}
```

Any help will be massively appreciated!

Thanks,

Ollie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your javascript code that is setting the background is overwriting the `background-size` property in your css.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var imageCount = 1;
    var total = 6;
    window.setInterval(function photoA() {
       var headbar = document.getElementById('headbar');
       imageCount = imageCount + 1;
       if(imageCount > total){imageCount = 1;}   
       headbar.style.backgroundImage = "url('../img/img"+ imageCount +".JPG')";
     }
   ,1000);
 </script>
```

```css
#headbar {
  height: 50vh;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-top: 60px;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center;
  color: #eee;
}
```

This should fix the problem. I deleted the `background-position` property, since this has no function and moved the `background-repeat` to the *CSS*. Only the `background-image` gets set from the code.

Remember that JavaScript code always takes precedence over your *CSS rules* except when you use the `!important` flag on a css property.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! i thought this would work it led me back to another error, in my last question someone said you can't use backgroundimage and think that might be what causing this error, now there is nothing at all showing! Any chance you know why? (its just blank now)

Comment: @OllieKlein If you've copy pasted my code, there was a `"` missing. Should work now. I couldn't imagine why backgroundImage wouldn't work while background works.